# offsetting lines

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, angle

Two strips of width 1 intersect at an angle α. Find the distance C between the intersection points of strip sides, as shown in the attached drawing.

[image]

Comment: **Here is a reworded version of the question:**

Two strips of width 1 intersect at an angle $\alpha$. Find the distance $c$ between the intersection points of strip sides, as shown in the attached drawing.

Comment: Your drawing is well thought out, but the question needs rewording.

Comment: Modified using your explanation. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your drawing, when the "offset" (strip width) is 1, the formula for the length of segment $c$ is
$$
c = {1\over\sin{\alpha\over2}} = \csc {\alpha\over2},
$$
where $\alpha$ is the angle formed by the two vectors (so ${\alpha\over2}$ is your "half-angle").

This is due to the fact that $c$ is the hypotenuse of a right triangle that has a leg of length $1$ opposite the angle ${\alpha\over2}$.